# How to convert a TimeStamp object into JSON

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the size of the Firestore documents. I planned to convert the document into JSON. I got the result if the document does not contain a TimeStamp field. but if there are TimeStamp Fields in the document, The following error was thrown:

```
Error: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'Timestamp'
```

This is the code tried:

```dart
Future<int> getDocumentSize() async {
  try {
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await incomeCollectionRef.get();
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> serializedDocs = [];

    if (querySnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
      serializedDocs = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) {
        Map<String, dynamic> data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        if (data.containsKey('FromDate') && data['FromDate'] is Timestamp) {
          data['FromDate'] = (data['FromDate'] as Timestamp)
              .toDate()
              .toUtc()
              .toIso8601String();
        }
        
        return data;
      }).toList();
    } else {
      print('No documents found.');
    }

    // Convert the document data to a JSON string
    String jsonData = jsonEncode(serializedDocs);

    // Calculate the size of the JSON string in bytes
    int sizeInBytes = utf8.encode(jsonData).length;

    print(sizeInBytes);
    return sizeInBytes;
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error: $e');
    return 0; // Handle the error as needed
  }
}
```

Additional Calculation Will be added.

How can I convert the TimeStamp into JSON? Is there any method to see the Firestore document size?

Comment: check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html and read `toEncodable` documentation

Comment: Are you sure the `TimeStamp` is put into the `'FromDate'` field and not in another? Maybe it's in `'fromDate'` instead. Might be a good idea to print the `serializedDocs` right before the `jsonEncode` to debug where there exactly is a `TimeStamp` still

Comment: @pskink the code indicates that he tries to convert the TimeStamp to an Iso8601String so the indicated error shouldn't even come in the first place, so the question is more like "Why are there even still `TimeStamp` objects in the `serializedDocs`?"

Comment: @Ivo hmmm, maybe he used a different key (not `FromDate`)?

Comment: @Ivo I just saw your first comment and it exactly explains what I meant - btw that's why it's better to use `toEncodable` since it can be called when JSON encoding for any key

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got from Flutter document about the json encode function.

```
import "dart:convert";

class CustomClass {
  final String text;
  final DateTime time;
  final int value;
  CustomClass({required this.text, required this.time, required this.value});
  CustomClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : text = json['text'],
  time = json["time"], 
        value = json['value'];

  static Map<String, dynamic> toJson(CustomClass value) =>
      {'text': value.text, 'time': value.time.toString(), 'value': value.value};
}

void main() {
  final CustomClass cc = CustomClass(text: 'Dart', time: DateTime.now(), value: 123);
  final jsonText = jsonEncode({'cc': cc},
      toEncodable: (Object? value) => value is CustomClass
          ? CustomClass.toJson(value)
          : throw UnsupportedError('Cannot convert to JSON: $value'));
  print(jsonText); // {"cc":{"text":"Dart","value":123}}
}
```

Output: **{"cc":{"text":"Dart","time":"2024-01-25 08:02:37.492","value":123}}**

Try to get the 'FromDate' variable from DateTime format and convert it to a string value, then you can convert it to JSON object type.

Or you can try this;

```
if (querySnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
      serializedDocs = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) {
        Map<String, dynamic> data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        if (data.containsKey('FromDate') && data['FromDate'] is Timestamp) {
          data['FromDate'] = (data['FromDate'] as Timestamp)
              .toDate()
              .toString()
        }
        
        return data;
      }).toList();
```